# Select the span in the table last row with id ends with

Tags: jquery, html

Hi all I am having a table where my id is `myTable` what I am doing is would like to fetch the span element which is hidden, as I am using asp.net gridivew I am getting that control with some auto generate id as follows and when I try this I am getting  the value `$("#myTable_ctl22_rowCount").text()` what I am trying to do I would like to find that span dynamically I tried few like `$("[id$='rowCount']")` by finding the last row but no luck

`$("#myTable tbody>tr>").last().find($("[id$='_rowCount']")).val()` can some one help me

Comment: Have you tried $("#myTable tbody tr:last").find($("[id$='_rowCount']")).val(). It will be more helpful if you share your generated HTML

Answer (score 0):

You were close to it, you need use `text()` instead of `val()` as span element don't have value but text, you can try below -

```
$("#myTable tbody tr:last").find("span[id$='_rowCount']").text();
```

```js
$(function(){
  var value = $("#myTable tbody tr:last").find("span[id$='_rowCount']").text();
  console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Id</th><th>Name</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td><td><span id="1_rowCount">one</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td><span id="2_rowCount">two</span></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes but no luck, seems this is working `$("#myTable tbody>tr>").find($("[id$='_rowCount']")).
last().text()`

Comment: my posted answer work see code snippet, can you post your html code also so that i can take a look at it.